# Remove NOT duplicated objects from two lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Well, I've read a lot about removing duplicated values from `lists`, but nothing about **maintaining** those that are in fact **duplicated** in another list.  I'll try to explain my problem:

I have to read some values from a DB and save every entry (integer entry) that matches my searching criterias. This operation is done *n* times, since it's a loop operation. The returning object must be a List (or ArrayList, or whatever list implementation is the most adequate for my purpose).

To make it clear, some *pseudocode*:

```
for (int i=0; i<nElements; i++) {

    tempList = getEntriesFromDb(i);

    if (i==0)
     result=tempList;

    else 
     //this is where I should maintain those entries that are in fact duplicated
     // in both tempList and result
     result = maintainDuplicates(result,tempList);

    }

retun result;
```

I would like to know some proposals for my problem. The question is, I could do it making a new loop that extracts every single entry from the lists, create a (third!!) *temporal list* to save them there, etc.. But I am really aware that this will cause a bottleneck in my implementation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: [`List#retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)), but no matter what it's going to be an `O(n)` operation. Consider using sets instead of lists.

Comment: A Set would be more efficient. And it also has a retainAll() method. @MattBall: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key operation here is looking up each element of one list in the other. That can be a slow operation. If the lists can be long, I suggest creating a HashSet `workingHash` that contains all elements of one list, and then doing a retainAll(workingHash) on the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can start iterate list1 elements and the current element need to verify in list2 ( `index = list2.indexOf(curElementInList1)` if index is > -1 than you add it to the result (the list3).

This is the slowest method, but simplest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sorted collection like `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` so that you will have sorted collection to compare. Then in sorted order, you can iterate through 2 collections as its sorted it will help you to find duplicate elements in 2n time that is o(n) time.

e.g. If you have DB result as `1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15` and tempList as `2 5 8 11` then

You can start iterating DB result and tempList at same time. Start with first element 1-2
So 1 is not present in `tempList` so 1 is not duplicate and so on. So comparisons and results will be like this.

1-2 Remove 1. Because DB result element less than `tempList` element, get next DB result ele

3-2 No remove. `tempList`  element less than DB result element, get next `tempList`  element so on

3-5 Remove 3. Because DB result element less than `tempList` element, get next DB result ele

5-5 Both are same so move to next element in both.

7-8 Because DB result element less than `tempList` element, get next DB result ele

9-8 No remove. `tempList`  element less than DB result element, get next `tempList`  element so on

9-11 Remove 9. Because DB result element less than `tempList` element, get next DB result ele

11-11 Both are same so move to next element in both.

So this is how you will get 5,11 as result.

Comment: I don't see how using a sorted set changes the asymptotic runtime.

Comment: With sorted collection, you will always be sure whether there is or there isn't possibility of element exist in collection or not. E.g. if you have list which contains list of 2,4,6,8,10 then while comparing 3 you first compare with 2 and it may exist but once you check with next element i.e.4, then you are sure 3 doesnt exist in list, you dont need to traverse whole list for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
result.retainAll(tempList);
```